# Logo is deploy in and present but not shown at front end

Tags: frontend, logo

My Logo is present at the pub media folder and also the Image src is correct
but not showing up on the front end.

I have tried cache flush. setup upgrade, static content deploy, di compile, and re-index everything.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you image added admin section or using xml ???

Comment: Before It was through XML now added through Backend admin

Comment: logo class hide using css display none ???